# AngularJS, replacing hard-coded json with $http.get and rendering the result

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

If I switch from the hard-coded items list in the following jsfiddle
 http://jsfiddle.net/rubyoma/bFJZK/
using a plain $http

```
$http.get('/mypath.json').then (response) =>
  response.data)
```

The data is async and come back after the table is rendered. I don't need to listen for changes, all needed is the json and search/sort client side (as it works right now). How would you make this work with the http get?

Post-accept EDIT: For tables I'd check out http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to replace the existing values in `$scope.items` with a `$http` request that fetches the values.

First - move the hard coded entries into the JSON file.
Second - remove the hard coded item entries in the controller.
Third - Have the following http call:

```
$http.get('/path/to/your/json/file')
    .success(function (result) {
        $scope.items = result;
        //We now have the data with us. Prepare for display
        $scope.search();
    });
```

Fourth - Remove the `$scope.search()` at line 100 - you can see that it is now called *after* the items have been fetched.

That's it. You don't have to change anything else - No listener is needed. The moment the async call returns with the items, your code will prepare the items and display.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3pFebNjh6NMjOPCyokip?p=preview) that demonstrates the code.

Comment: the plunkr shows unrelated things, 'Map syntax', 'string syntax'. Did your plunkr get overridden or did you forgot to save? I see the data.json that's relevant, but that's it.

Comment: I think it got overridden... Are you still looking for a complete example?

Comment: no need, it worked as you proposed! It redraws the table, I guess that's part of ng-repeat. A bit magical, but any new framework feels like that in the beginning. Thanks again, katootie, you rock!